Upgrade pacemaker corosync drbd Cluster from centos7 to almalinux
I have an active passive pacemaker Cluster for vms running with drbd 84 and corosync in centos7.
AS centos7 eol is coming soon I am in the need of upgrading the cluster to a newer distribution. Almalinux 8 or 9 would be in my choice.
What I saw is that in Almalinux repositories drbd Version 9 is already in the repos. Corosync and pacemaker Versions are also minimum 1 major version higher than in CentOS 7 repos.
I would need to upgrade the cluster somehow as I have there systems running which have to be online 24/7.
Possible scenarios which come to my head:
1.) Upgrading drbd from 84 to 9. Afterwards upgrading to latest drbd 9x. Afterwards set secondary node to offline mode and reinstalling with Almalinux. Afterwards rejoining the cluster. Then moving vms and doing the same with the second node.
2.) Setting up a second pacemaker cluster on Alma Linux in parallel. Migrating the vms with virsh migrate live (libvirt from sig repository).
Has anyone already had a scenario like this and how got it solved?

DRBD 8.xx -> 9.xx upgrades don’t go smoothly. We ended up with …

Performing production VMs backup with Veeam

Making sure we can actually restore and run VMs from (1), DR cluster is recommended (we got one of course)

Devastating existing DRBD 8.xx cluster and wiping off aging CentOS (out of support soon)

Installing latest Debian from scratch

Deploying DRBD 9.xx + Corosync + Pacemaker

Restoring out production VMs from (1) to our brand-new shiny cluster from (4+5)


This approach worked. Trying in-place updates? Not so much!
UPDATE: We’re not very happy with V9 stability as of now. This particular customer insisted on DRBD back in the days, but is considering hardware SAN now. FYI.
